# How can I use "For" Keyword in IActionResult name of .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

As google suggest in this page:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184?hl=en

Simple URLs should convey content information

[image]

My product name is tools for car,so my url is 
http://localhost:4413/Product/tools-for-car

Now the problem is in the Controller,when I use this name in controller,Visual Studio report error for the keyword "For" as below:
[image]

I wonder if there is a way that I can use this url name?Or I can only change the name.Thank you.

Comment: Product name will the the parameter to your action method(`Index`). See the routing tutorial.

Comment: Have a look at the routing fundamentals https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: the reason it red squiggled too is that its invalid naming for the method.  now if you had used underscores `_` then it would have worked but the proper method to achieving the route in question is what @martin has provided for an answer

Comment: @mvermef thank you for your warm help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want is to specify the routes explicitly:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ProductController : Controller
{
   [Route("tools-for-car")]
   public IActionResult CarTools() { … }
}
```

See the [Routing to controller actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1) documentation for more detail.

Comment: Thank you,but I read this:https://andrewlock.net/url-culture-provider-using-middleware-as-mvc-filter-in-asp-net-core-1-1-0/ and found it is more digestible than microsoft's.